# How do I deploy my separated Django front and back end via Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, deployment, django-rest-framework, heroku-cli

I have two Django projects, for front and back end (using DRF). i want to deploy them both in Heroku, on the same url (eg backend.website.com for the back end and website.com for front end). Then the backend would only whitelist the front.

How do i do this (if it's possible) on Heroku? Would they need to be on separate dyno's?

Comment: Have you tried the steps described in [this article](https://dev.to/256hz/deploying-a-two-repo-app-to-one-domain-on-heroku-2mhl)?

Comment: @crimsonpython24 ah, that's exactly what i'm looking for, dunno how i didn't find that. cheers!